# Retrieve indices of rows that contain NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I try to retrieve for each row containing NaN values all the corresponding indices.

```
      A    B    C    D
0  11.4  1.3  2.0  NaN
1  11.4  1.3  NaN  NaN
2  11.4  1.3  2.8  0.7
3  NaN   NaN  2.8  0.7
```

The desired result :
[0,1,3]

I'm looking for a pandas way to be able to deal with my huge dataset.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use for better performance filtering by `index` values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
idx = df.index[df.isnull().any(axis=1)].tolist()
print (idx)
[0, 1, 3]
```

**Explanation**:

First compare by `NaN`s values:

```
print (df.isnull())
       A      B      C      D
0  False  False  False   True
1  False  False   True   True
2  False  False  False  False
3   True   True  False  False
```

And then check if at least one per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df.isnull().any(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Using loc

```
df.loc[df.isna().any(axis=1)].index.tolist()
```